# stacking columns into 1 column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, reshape

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
ID Time U1 U2 U3 U4 ...
1  20    1  2 3  5 .. 
2  20    2  5 9  4 ..
3  20    2  5 6  4 ..
.
.

And I would need to keep it like: 

ID Time  U
1  20    1
1  20    2
1  20    3
1  20    5
2  20    2
2  20    5
2  20    9
2  20    4
3  20    2
3  20    5
3  20    6
3  20    4
```

I tried with:

```
X <- read.table("mydata.txt", header=TRUE, sep=",")
X_D <- as.data.frame(X)
X_new <- stack(X_D, select = -c(ID, Time))
```

But I haven't managed to get the data into that form. Honestly, I have little experience with stacking/transposing, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is commonly called conversion from wide format to long format. However, the way you've defined it, you lose information about which column a piece of data came from. Incidentally, the package `reshape2` covers this sort of transformation.

Comment: Additionally, you're more likely to get the answer you really want if you provide a really easy way for answerers to get example data into R to work with. Providing what's in the file isn't simple, but providing `dput()` output of the original example dataframe object IS!

Comment: There's also a solution with `tidyr::gather()`

Comment: @Phil - can you enumerate it?  I'm looking for the tidyr equivalent of the JMP "stack columns" platform.

Answer (score 16):

Here's the `stack` approach:

```
dat2a <- data.frame(dat[1:2], stack(dat[3:ncol(dat)]))
dat2a
#    ID Time values ind
# 1   1   20      1  U1
# 2   2   20      2  U1
# 3   3   20      2  U1
# 4   1   20      2  U2
# 5   2   20      5  U2
# 6   3   20      5  U2
# 7   1   20      3  U3
# 8   2   20      9  U3
# 9   3   20      6  U3
# 10  1   20      5  U4
# 11  2   20      4  U4
# 12  3   20      4  U4
```

This is very similar to `melt` from "reshape2":

```
library(reshape2)
dat2b <- melt(dat, id.vars=1:2)
dat2b
#    ID Time variable value
# 1   1   20       U1     1
# 2   2   20       U1     2
# 3   3   20       U1     2
# 4   1   20       U2     2
# 5   2   20       U2     5
# 6   3   20       U2     5
# 7   1   20       U3     3
# 8   2   20       U3     9
# 9   3   20       U3     6
# 10  1   20       U4     5
# 11  2   20       U4     4
# 12  3   20       U4     4
```

And, very similar to @TylerRinker's answer, but not dropping the "times", is to just use `sep = ""` to help R guess time and variable names.

```
dat3 <- reshape(dat, direction = "long", idvar=1:2, 
                varying=3:ncol(dat), sep = "", timevar="Measure")
dat3
#        ID Time Measure U
# 1.20.1  1   20       1 1
# 2.20.1  2   20       1 2
# 3.20.1  3   20       1 2
# 1.20.2  1   20       2 2
# 2.20.2  2   20       2 5
# 3.20.2  3   20       2 5
# 1.20.3  1   20       3 3
# 2.20.3  2   20       3 9
# 3.20.3  3   20       3 6
# 1.20.4  1   20       4 5
# 2.20.4  2   20       4 4
# 3.20.4  3   20       4 4
```

In all three of those, you end up with four columns, not three, like you describe in your desired output. However, as @ndoogan points out, by doing so, you're loosing information about your data. If you're fine with that, you can always drop that column from the resulting `data.frame` quite easily (for example, `dat2a <- dat2a[-4]`.

Answer (score 2):

With base `reshape`:

```
dat <- read.table(text="ID Time U1 U2 U3 U4
1  20    1  2 3  5
2  20    2  5 9  4
3  20    2  5 6  4", header=TRUE)


colnames(dat) <- gsub("([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9])", "\\1.\\2", colnames(dat))
reshape(dat, varying=3:ncol(dat), v.names="U", direction ="long", timevar = "Time", 
    idvar = "ID")
```

Comment: (+1) It could be worth specifying what "base reshape" means in the context of another reshape answer that depends on reshape2 package.

Comment: This should do it for anyone wondering: `?reshape`

Comment: +1 for matching the output exactly, but I do also worry about loosing information this way.

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Agreed.  In this case I didn't see it as a problem so I dropped it to match the user's wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use melt():

```
library(reshape2)

new_data <- melt(old_data, id.vars=c("ID","Time"),
    value.name = "U")
```

Then remove the 'variable' column:

```
new_data$variable <- NULL
```

Comment: Oops, this will actually order the U rows by rows in the old_data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:4, function(i)structure(dat[,c("ID", "Time", paste0("U",i))], names=c("ID", "Time", "U"))))
```

Where `dat` is your data.frame...

Comment: Thanks! It gives me an error though: 'undefined columns selected' here '[.data.frame'(dat, ,[,c("ID", "Time",

Comment: Hi @user2263330, it works for me with `dat <- data.frame(ID=1:3, Time=20, U1=1:3, U2=4:6, U3=7:9, U4=10:12)`. What are the names of your data.frame?